# What about different attitudes towards rpg?

Tags: discussion, tags, answers

There's gamism, simulation and story-telling. Lots of questions have different answers depending on what people want from the game.

eg. A question about mapping
 - in dungeon-crawls it's essential especially that DM is supposed to require players to find their way in the maze.
 - in story-telling and alike it's the other way around - players shouldn't bother drawing maps of cities assuming that every non-retarded dwarf/human/elf will find his way (and if not, the GM will say so).

Maybe we should add tags to answers that would refer to 3 common attitudes.

What do you think?

Answer (score 4):

Only when they're highly related to the question.

For example some questions should be tagged `storytelling` if the asker is asking for a question wants an answer that doesn't have an emphasis on rules.

We shouldn't try to make a global tagging scheme out of this.

Comment: That's right, but I'm worried that people would start arguing. And there's nthing worse than an argument where both sides are right, but they forgot to compare contexts.

Comment: @naugtur I think we have enough problems without predicting them.

Comment: @C. Ross Ok, I can agree on that :)

Answer (score 3):

Yeah there's a huge war out there between people that believe in the "threefold" approach and people that hate them...  Best to avoid it when possible.  It always turns into a semantics debate.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the general premise that people approach roleplaying with differing attitudes, but I fairly strongly disagree that the three attitudes listed are the canonical three. Now, what I think doesn't matter so much, except that it indicates that you might have trouble getting people to agree on the list of tags.

If someone wants to ask a question specifically pointed at narrativist techniques, I think that's a good time to use a tag, but I don't think we need to force people into defining themselves in ways they might not be comfortable with.